# Why window.location not work inside ajax in iphone safari?

Tags: iphone, ajax, mobile, safari, popup

I have a simple page that call the function below when onclick:

```
 function launch_new_window() {
        var popup_window = window.open('/test_popup_wait.html', 'popup_window', 'width=500,height=300');

        $.getJSON( "/ajax/test_popup?seconds=2", function( data ) {
            if (data.status) {
                //alert('Confirm');
                popup_window.location = '/test_popup_ok.html';

            }
        });
    }
```

When the ajax call done, it should load the test_popup_ok.html page.  It works for any browser on computer.

However, it doesn't work on iphone / ipad safari. It doesn't load the test_popup_ok.html page.  The funny thing is if I put alert befor popup_window.location.  it will work.

Why is that?  How to properly fix that and launch test_popup_ok.html page without putting the alert() call?

Comment: Have you try `setTimeout`? Looks like `popup_window` is not created then you change `popup_window.location`

Comment: I've tried.  Still doesn't work.